# Where to find a direct link or torrent for Ubuntu Gnome ALTERNATE ISO?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, alternate

I can't find any place to download Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS in alternate ISO version.

Doesn't it exist ?

Comment: It looks like alternate iso are not built any more.

Comment: Why to down vote my question ? Is it a stupid question ?? Yes a accepted the "duplicate" flag but the reason is the solution is the same for the linked question and mine... but the question is not the same, originally... So, I don't understand why my question deserve down voting. Plus, other users could ask this question in the futur so... They will find more easily my question and its answers that the linked one (via the duplicate flag), because they will be searching the same distro as me. If the question is down voted, the visibility decrease...

Comment: I do not know who downvoted. I can upvote if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of at least 14.04, alternate ISOs are only built for [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO).

Answer (score 2):

It is clearly linked on the [Get Ubuntu GNOME](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/GetUbuntuGNOME/LTS) page. There are no "alternate" ISO images for derivatives, generally.

Comment: And where is the alternate there?

Comment: What alternate? Ubuntu GNOME *is* the alternate.

Comment: No. There used to be alternate CD images without the GUI installer.

Comment: AFAIK, derivatives do not build alternate ISOs.

Comment: @dobey Well, actually there is no longer an alternative ISO for Ubuntu itself. Only the Lubuntu flavour has one

Comment: @muru The network installer for 15.10 is clearly linked on the Ubuntu alternative downloads page, and the Server image is a text-only install as well.

Comment: @dobey Netinst is not the same as the alternate ISO.